# rotationY issue on large interactive display wall (8000x2500)

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, air, stage3d

I am working with a large interactive touch screen that is 8000x2500. I am able to fill the display with many vector objects, large bitmaps (full screen high quality images), etc. I am having an issue with any sprite that contains an image past x=4096. The sprite will display just fine until I try to to rotate the it on the Y axis, the sprite either disappears or cuts off right at 4096. I would imagine it would happen trying to rotate on any axis, but Y is the one I am trying to get working.

Doesn't any one have any ideas about this? I'm happy to provide any information needed...

Comment: More information...I'm using AIR 4.0 with Flash Player 12. The OS is Windows 7 (x86, 4 cores) with 16GB RAM, and the graphics card is AMD FirePro W8000.

Answer (score 3):

Please, don't forget about BitmapData limitation in ActionScript

> In AIR 1.5 and Flash Player 10, the maximum size for a BitmapData object is 8,191 pixels in width or height, and the total number of pixels cannot exceed 16,777,215 pixels.

For screen you specified: 8000x2096 but not 8000x2500 …

If you will count limitation in code, you will be able to do anything with Bitmap that you want ;)

Comment: Well I am using AIR 4.0 and Flash Player 12. I have two other applications that use the whole screen. One app displays full images (8000x2500) that fade in/out to the next without any issues at all. The other app has 800+ sprites with text data that can enlarge and play videos. I can even have multiple videos playing at the same time and I have no issues whatsoever. That's why I'm so confused by this. The app I'm having issues with can display everything fine across the entire screen _until_ I try to flip one using rotationY to see the "back" of it.

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 things that can limit you:

1) As @NicolasSiver said, in AIR 1.5 and FP10, you're limited to a max size of 8,191 width or height. If you can update to AIR 3 or FP11, these restrictions have been limited, and you're only limited by the OS

2) The stage size itself is limited. I haven't been able to find any information for anything higher than FP10, but from http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/size-limits-swf-bitmap-files.html#main_Stage_size_limits:

> The usable stage size limit in Flash Player 10 is roughly 4,050 pixels
>   by 4,050 pixels. However, the usable size of the stage varies
>   depending on the settings of the QUALITY tag. In some cases, it's
>   possible to see graphic artifacts when stage size approaches the 3840
>   pixel range.
>
> Changing quality affects the anti-aliasing of the stage.  When quality
>   is lower Flash Player, can display more stage area. For example, if
>   you draw a sprite or a bitmap 5,000 pixels wide, and quality is Low,
>   then it's possible that you correctly draw the sprite.  However, if
>   quality is high, Flash Player adjusts the limits of the visible stage
>   to fit within its available drawing memory. Therefore, the sprite
>   could cut off in the 4,050 pixel area.

As your problem is coming in when "an image past x=4096", it looks like it's the second case that's hitting you. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a whole pile you can do. Try:

- Lower the stage quality to it's lowest settings - if you're only working with `BitmapData`s, then it won't affect you anyway. This should stretch out your margin a bit, but probably not to 8000
- Update to the latest FP/AIR and experiment to see what the limits are
- Try Stage3D - going through the GPU might unlock something extra
- Use multiple SWFs/NativeApplications and communicate between them to get the effect you're looking for - this might be super awkward though
- Scale up the SWF itself - work at 4000x1250 and scale the SWF window 2x (NOTE: this may not work :D)

Comment: See my comment above please. Basically I am using AIR 4.0 and FP12. I only have issues when I try to flip one of these sprites that are positioned past x=4096. Initially when the app loads they are all perfect across the entire screen. When I try to flip one using rotationY, any sprite past x=4096 has the issue. I even tried just positioning one sprite past x=4096 and it still happened.